# How to install gettext mo files into /usr/share/locale using Automake?

Tags: internationalization, gettext, autotools, automake

For man pages, I can install them by:

```
man_MANS = \
    program.1 \
    program.5
```

Is there similar approach to install gettext mo files? like,

```
locale_MESSAGES = \
    program.mo.en_US \
    program.mo.zh_CN
```

instead of,

```
locale_en_USdir = ${localedir}/en_US/LC_MESSAGES
locale_zh_CNdir = ${localedir}/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES

locale_en_US_DATA = \
    po/en_US/program.mo

locale_zh_CN_DATA = \
    po/zh_CN/program.mo
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`gettextize`](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/gettextize-Invocation.html) program will create/update the Makefiles for you. See also [A. Duret-Lutz's autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/dl/autotools.pdf); the `gettext` parts starts at p. 468.